# How to hide print information of Makefile?

Tags: makefile

when Makefile execute some tasks, il will print many information in console, can we choose to hide them? when I have many .o to generate, these information will be too many to see and they are just meaningless if we don't read them.

The following code

```
$(obj)environment.o: $(src)environment.c
                      $(CC) $(AFLAGS) -Wa, --no-warn \
                             -DENV_CRC=$(shell $(obj)../tools/envcrc) \
                             -c -o $@ $(src)environment.c
```

will print heavy information like

```
arm-linux-gcc -g  -Os   -fno-strict-aliasing  -fno-common -ffixed-r8 -msoft-float  
-D__KERNEL__ -DTEXT_BASE=0x01000000  
-I/home/mingzhao/Documents/bootloader/u-boot-1.2.0/include 
-fno-builtin -ffreestanding -nostdinc -isystem  
/home/mingzhao/Documents/bootloader/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/
gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include -pipe  -DCONFIG_ARM 
-D__ARM__ -march=armv4 -mabi=apcs-gnu -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  
-c -o environment.o environment.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option `make --silent` which will suppress output for all targets. If you want to suppress output for some commands, you can prefix them by `@`

Answer (score 3):

The "right" way to handle this (IMO) is to add this to your makefile:

```
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:
```

Then in your rules where you don't *ever* want the command printed (for example, an `echo` statement as in Beta's answer below) you prefix it with `@`.  For all other commands, you don't prefix it with `@`.

What this does is enable "silent" mode by default (because the variable `VERBOSE` is not set and so this resolves to the `.SILENT` pseudo-target).

Then if you want to see everything, you add a `VERBOSE=1` (actually you can set it to any non-empty value, so `VERBOSE=true` if you prefer).  When you do that it turns off "silent" mode because the above line expands to `1.SILENT:` (or `true.SILENT:` or whatever) which is meaningless to make.

Comment: Nice. I see you've written it up in more detail at https://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

Answer (score 1):

I like something like this:

```
$(obj)environment.o: $(src)environment.c
    @echo building $@
    @$(CC) $(AFLAGS) -Wa, --no-warn \
      -DENV_CRC=$(shell $(obj)../tools/envcrc) \
      -c -o $@ $(src)environment.c
```

The `@echo ...` gives a minimal status message, the '@' in front of the `$(CC)` suppresses standard output (but still allows error messages).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax : `@$(CC) $(AFLAGS) -Wa, --no-warn \...`